# It is necessary uniqueness validation in associations has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I create uniqueness validation in my model to garantice that user_id in table was unique, but I am not sure if association has_one do that.

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #association macros
  has_one :balance
end
```

Balance Model

```
class Balance < ActiveRecord::Base
  #association macros
  belongs_to :user

  #validation macros
  validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true #uniqueness is necessary?
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to have a `validates_presence_of` for that since it is handled in your database. However, to not have to handle a database error, it is better to do it in your model like you have. Rails built in error handlers for validation will then work.

If your table data shows that it cannot be null/nil, then the validation is on the database itself and will return an error which is much harder to handle. You will get a system error and the Rails 'better errors' message. Which basically is breaking your app.

If you do the model validation as you have in your Model using the...

```
validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

then Rails will allow you to control these error messages within your app. You can choose to ignore them (bad) and have data entry almost silently fail. Or, you can turn on label_errors along with flash messages in your controller to allow users to see what is wrong with the data they are trying to enter on a form.

Comment: sorry but My question it is about uniqueness validation

Comment: Can you rephrase your question then? It asks if it is necessary to validate uniqueness in a has_one association.

Comment: Yes and your answer was "It is not necessary to have a `validates_presence_of` for that since it is handled in your database."  can you please explain a little bit more?